# How to return multiple values from a Table-Valued Function to Speed Up Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am trying to clean up some addresses.  I have a table that has city, state, zip all on one line, and I'm trying to parse them out.   I created a Table-Valued Function because my understanding is that it's quicker.

The customerAddress table is a bit wonky, it has an entry for each line of the address.  So a customer_id may have between 2 and 4 records.  My WHERE looks for the last 4 being numeric, and it having a , in it, and the first line should never have the city, state, zip.

Here's what the customerAddress table looks like:

```
customer_id address_line_id address_data
10447           3           CULVER CITY, CA  90233-6011
10893           3           VIRGINIA BEACH, VA  23452
10461           3           DOWNERS GROVE,  IL  60515
10894           1           1111 BOHM DRIVE
10894           2           PO BOX 109
10894           3           LITTLE CHUTE, WI  54140-0109
10895           1           1990 WEST 32ND AVE.
10895           2           DENVER, CO 80211
```

So here's my query:

```
SELECT customer_id, address_line_id, address_data, oa.*
  INTO #tmpAddress
  FROM customerAddress
  OUTER APPLY
 ( SELECT * FROM [dbo].[parseCityStateZip](customerAddress.address_data)    ) oa
  WHERE
    address_data LIKE '%,%' AND 
    ISNUMERIC( RIGHT(address_data,4) ) = 1 AND
    address_line_id != 1
ORDER BY customer_id, address_line_id
```

Here is the execution plan for the query.  If I'm reading it correctly (which I probably am not) the Table-Valued Function took 9m 33s to run, but the Filter was 123%??
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S13IITvZw

I used the `OUTER APPLY` because I thought it was better than calling the function for each field, and there isn't anything I can join it on for a `LEFT JOIN`.

Here is my Table-Valued Function that I am calling in the `OUTER APPLY`

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[parseCityStateZip] (@inStr varchar(255) )
    RETURNS @returnTable
      TABLE (
        [city] varchar(255),
        [state]  varchar(255),
        [zip] varchar(12),
        [country] varchar(50) NULL,
        [intlFlag] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT(0))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE
        @newStr varchar(255), @strCity varchar(255), @strState varchar(255), @strZip varchar(12), @strCountry varchar(255),
        @strIntlFlag bit

    -- Determines if Zip Code is 5 or 9 Digits
    --  Stores to variable and chops it off saving the remainign to @newStr
    IF CHARINDEX('-', @inStr, 0) > 0
      BEGIN
        SELECT @strZip = RIGHT(@inStr, 10)
        SELECT @newStr = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@inStr, 0, LEN(@inStr) - 9))
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        SELECT @strZip = RIGHT(@inStr, 5)
        SELECT @newStr = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@inStr, 0, LEN(@inStr) - 4))
      END

    -- Looks for the , separating City, State
    --  Saves everything before the , and City, and after as State
    --  Use TRIM to remove extra spaces before or after the State
    SELECT @strCity =  TRIM( SUBSTRING( @newStr, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @newStr, 0) ) )
    SELECT @strState = ULTRA.dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters( TRIM( SUBSTRING( @newStr, CHARINDEX(',', @newStr, 0) + 1, LEN(@newStr) - CHARINDEX(',', @newStr, 0) ) ) )
    
    -- Checks to see if the State matches a state in the info table, and is in the United States
    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [Country] = 'United States' AND ([State_long] = @strState OR [State_abbr] = @strState))
        SELECT @strCountry = 'United States', @strIntlFlag = 0
    ELSE
        SELECT @strCountry = 'INTERNATIONAL', @strIntlFlag = 1

    INSERT INTO @returnTable VALUES (@strCity, @strState, @strZip, @strCountry, @strIntlFlag)
    RETURN  
END
```

And here's the Execution plan for good measure:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkFCQawZP

Is there a way to pull all the fields inline in a query, something like:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    address_data,
    (SELECT * FROM [parseCityStateZip](address_data))
  FROM customerAddress
```

Would that speed up the query?  If not, what can be done to speed it up?

I'm using the Latest SQL Server and SSMS

Comment: 1 - Please share execution plans via [pastetheplan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). The 123% is because of statistics, the engine estimates it wil return N results, but it returs more then N results resulting in a larger then 100%

Comment: If you want to speed it up, you may need to inline all logic instead of using table valued and scalar functions. (So including RemoveNonAlphaCharacters) See https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/user-defined-scalar-functions-suck-even-when-they-dont-access-data/

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Hah, cool.  I'll do that for the plans.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Yeah, I wrote it out 'longhand' and it runs in 2sec now.  I was hoping to have a decent reusable function but 9min vs 2sec is unacceptable :(

Comment: This is often a trade-off when performance tuning. Performance vs Maintainability. 
What you could consider is adding computed columns for some columns (ZipCode and City) this way, those are at least reusable. State,Country and the flag are different cases since they use other functions and tables.